# Recommended dsPIC schematic design and voltage regulator

Tags: pic

I'm having some problems with my dsPIC33EP64MC202. I believe it is a hardware problem, but I'm not sure yet.

I designed the hardware, designed the firmware, and everything was fine in debug mode. So, I stopped to use it in debug mode and I programmed it definitely. One month later it stopped with no reason, so, I tried to debug it and, when I tried to load the code, a message appears to inform "Invalid ID". I tried everything, I plug it, unplug and, finally, I came to the conclusion that it meant that the dsPIC died. So, I put another dsPIC, same model, and it worked fine, but, approximately one month later, the same thing happened, it stopped and when I tried to debug, the message appeared: "Target Device ID (0x1d390000) is an Invalid Device ID". So, another dsPIC lost.

Well, I will put here my schematic and the specification in datasheet. As you can see, the connection in Vcap is not the recommended, I put it in VDD instead of GND. But, if I do not put Vcap in VDD, debug does not work. What can I do? Would it be the responsible for the dsPIC fail?

[image: dsPIC schematic]

Another hypothesis is that the problem would be due to the voltage regulator, I use a LM317 to convert 13.8V to 3.3V. The device need to be functioning 24hs, is this source power a good choice?

[image: voltage regulator schematic]

Obervation: I'm sorry, the schematic of the regulator voltage was not updated. There are no resistors of 375 ohms, but one of 412 ohms instead. So, the calculation will be:

1.25 V * [1 + (412 ohm/240 ohm)] + 50 µA * 187.5 ohm = 3,41V

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presented design has two fundamental mistakes.

(1) it doesn't apply correct hardware RESET (MCLR). This pin is clearly needs to be connected with a RC delay. The delay is usually required to make sure that power-on voltages all reached stable valid levels before the MCLR is deasserted (set HIGH).

(2) The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS-70657B.pdf) says, ***"The VCAP pin must not be connected to VDD"***. This pin must have a 4.7uF low-ESR cap to make the internal 1.8V regulator stable, and left alone. It must be really stressful to feed all core logic with 3.3V while it was designed for 1.8 V.

There is also a BOR (brown-out) circuit attached to the 1.8V regulator, which is also a part of proper reset sequence..

In short, this design was working by accident, due to some lucky timing of voltage ramp, and the BOR circuit (VCAP being connected to VDD) did provide accidentally correct internal reset. So you are right, it eventually is related to power supply. But after exceeding the core voltage for long time (a month), I am afraid this particular chip is fried now, at least partially.

ADDENDUM: Always follow manufacturer's recommendations. There is absolutely no reason not to follow them, a lot of engineering effort and application field experience usually went into these recommendations.

Comment: @ Ali Chen, thank you very much. Yes, you're right. The recommendation is to isolate MCLR only during debug and programming. But , I didn't understand why when I didn't put the vcap on vdd, the debug process did not work. At first, vcap was not tied to vdd, it was as it is in recommendation, but, when I changed it, it worked. I was aware of the recommendation. I will redesign it and folow the recommendation. About the regulator voltage, I will add some protection too, at the LM317 there are some recommendations, but, do you have any suggestions? Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Daniel, the LM317 looks OK, except that linear regulator from 13 V to 3V will incur substantial losses and might become hot and will need a heat sink.

Comment: @Daniel - "*I didn't understand why when I didn't put the vcap on vdd, the debug process did not work*" That is what you need to investigate, when you can recreate that situation. However, it is too late to now change *this* question, into *that* question. Regarding the power supply: Since you mention that Vin = 13.8V, I suspect this is an automotive application. If so, there are plenty of opportunities to improve the robustness of the power supply, in addition to the helpful comment already from *Ali*. That is a subject for a question on its own also, but research previous questions first.

Comment: @SamGibson, there is something goofy about the MCLR pin, and the RC. The text on p.32, *"Therefore, specific  values of R and C will need to  be adjusted based on the application and PCB requirements"* doesn't make much sense. I would get their development/reference board, and implement the RC exactly as it is.

Comment: @AliChen, They do not have a reference board, only thing that I found about PCB was the recommended connections in section 2.0 of the datasheet

Comment: I will search for a development board, althoug, I found one before, but it was made for a especific application and it was a bit different of the recommendation too.